# Curl php - if condition

Tags: php, domdocument

HTML

```
<select id="myid">
    <option value="1" data-name="text 1" data-price="5">Text 1</option>
    <option value="2" data-name="text 2" data-price="10">Text 2</option>
</select>
```

My code below works fine but show me all the "data-price" with TagName "option". I would like to grab only one specif price. So I would like to add something like this:

```
<?php
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTMLFile('https://example.com');
$optionNodes = $doc->getElementById('myid')->getElementsByTagName('option');
foreach($optionNodes as $optionNode) {
// if $optionNode->getAttribute('data-name') = "text 2"
     echo $optionNode->getAttribute('data-price') . '<br/>';
}
?>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XPath to the rescue.

```
<?php
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTMLFile('https://example.com');
$xp=new DOMXPath($doc);
echo $xp->query("//option[@value='2']")->item(0)->getAttribute("data-price");
```

- gets the first element with the attribute `value="2"` and fetches it's `data-price` attribute.

likewise you can do

```
echo $xp->query("//option[@data-name='text 2']")->item(0)->getAttribute("data-price");
```

to fetch it by `data-name`, or you can even do

```
echo $xp->query("//option[text()='Text 2']")->item(0)->getAttribute("data-price");
```

to fetch it based on the text content, and even

```
echo $xp->query("//option[contains(text(),'Text 2')]")->item(0)->getAttribute("data-price");
```

to fetch it based on partial text content (this will fetch any `option` element which has `Text 2` anywhere in it's textContent.)

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($optionNode->getAttribute('data-name') == "text 2") {
    echo $optionNode->getAttribute('data-price') . '<br/>';
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain a little more about how your answer solves the OPs problem?

Comment: I got the impression OP knew the logic, just not the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Just add below condition in your code.

```
 <?php
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    @$doc->loadHTMLFile('https://example.com');
    $optionNodes = $doc->getElementById('myid')->getElementsByTagName('option');
    foreach($optionNodes as $optionNode) {
       if($optionNode->getAttribute('data-price') == "10"){
         echo $optionNode->getAttribute('data-price') . '<br/>';
       }
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try :

```
 echo $optionNode->getAttribute('data-price') == "text 2" ? $optionNode->getAttribute('data-price') . '<br/>' : '';
```